# How to fit an image into a sf and ggplot map in r and add an onclick function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, geom-sf

I would like to fit an image into this map plot in r. How can I add an onclick function
to each country in the plotly plot. Are there any themes in r that can be used on hover text box?

```
africa.plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = africa) +
  geom_sf(data = selected_africa, aes(), fill = "transparent", color = "brown") +  # Highlight selected countries
  geom_sf_text(data = selected_africa, aes(label = name_long), color = "black", size = 3, nudge_y = 0.1) +
  theme_void()

africa_plotly <- ggplotly(africa.plot, tooltip = "text")
```

Comment: We do not have `africa` and `selected_africa`.

Comment: africa <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf", continent = "Africa")

selected_africa is just a set of countries that I have selected.